# Jest mock Typeorm Datasource in unit tests (without nestjs)

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing, jestjs, typeorm, ts-jest

I am working on creating unit tests for a project that uses Typeorm without Nestjs. The file I am creating unit tests for uses queryRunner to start a transaction. My problem is, I am not able to mock the Datasource. I tried multiple ways but the mock is never getting called to replace the actual Datasource that has access to the postgresql database. I saw some solutions to mock it, but they all use Nestjs, which I don't use in my case.

The error I am having in the tests right now is:

```
    Received promise rejected instead of resolved
    Rejected to value: [TypeORMError: Driver not Connected]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated since I'm not an expert in unit tests.

Here's an example of the code that I am having the issue with (replaced some names tho):

`datasource.ts`

```
//database config is defined in this file
export const datasource: DataSource = new DataSource(some_config);
```

`dummy.service.ts`

```
export const dummyService = () => {
    //datasource is imported from the above file
    const queryRunner = datasource.createQueryRunner();
    await queryRunner.startTransaction();

    try {
      const foundObject = await queryRunner.manager.getRepository(MyObject).findOne({
        where: { id: someId },
        lock: { mode: 'pessimistic_write' },
      });
      //some more database calls
    } catch (error) {
      await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
    } finally {
      await queryRunner.release();
    }
}
```

`mock.datasource.ts`

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

export const dataSourceMockFactory: () => MockType<DataSource> = jest.fn(
  () => ({
    createQueryRunner: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
      connect: jest.fn(),
      startTransaction: jest.fn(),
      release: jest.fn(),
      rollbackTransaction: jest.fn(),
      manager: {
        getRepository: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
          create: jest.fn(),
          findOne: jest.fn(() => {
            return getMyDummyObject();
          }),
        })),
        save: jest.fn(),
      },
    })),
  }),
);

export type MockType<T> = {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
  [P in keyof T]?: jest.Mock<{}>;
};
```

`dummy.unit.test.ts`

```
describe('dummy service test', () => {
  let dataSourceMock: MockType<Typeorm.DataSource>;

  beforeEach(async () => {

    // This method did not work
    jest.mock('typeorm', () => {
      const actual = jest.requireActual('typeorm');
      return {
        ...actual,
        DataSource: dataSourceMockFactory(),
      };
    });

    // The below method did not work either
    jest.mock('./../../db/datasource', () => ({
      datasource: dataSourceMockFactory(),
    }));
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('should test dummy service with transaction', async () => {
    // getting an error here
    await expect(
      dummyFunction(),
    ).resolves.not.toThrow();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an in-memory sqlite database:

```
const options: ConnectionOptions = {
  type: "sqlite",
  database: "memory",
  entities: [ User, Message ],
  logging: true
}
```

use that to call createConnection, and use that connection in your tests

fast, nicer than mocking, and works "similar enough" for unit tests.   integration tests for postgres will still be needed tho.

There are also things like pg-mem, if you rely on database-specific features:

https://github.com/oguimbal/pg-mem